# Class 3 implements i and extends c, i has a default method and c has a same method with different implementation. Which implementation applies for 3?

Tags: inheritance, java-8, extends, default-method

If I have a interface `i` and a class `c`, `i` has a default method (Java8) and `c` has a method with the same signature but with a different implementation. Which implementation applies to a class `3` that implements `i` and extends `c`?

Comment: What happens if you have i and i2 with a method with the same signature and have a class implement them both? Ooooh now that's interesting

Comment: @softarn you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

The method in C will be called. Class implementations have precedence to interfaces.